# I have a B2 visa. Can I make a stop over in the US without using my B2 visa

Tags: usa, canada, esta, b1-b2-visas, stopovers

I have already a B2 visa which I would like to use for my trip next year (April 2017).

However, I am flying over the US (with a stop over in the US) to Canada in December 2016. For this stop over I have an ESTA.

Does the B2 period of 6 months start as soon as I enter the US (in December 2016)? Which would mean that I need to re-apply for a B2 visa for my trip starting in April 2017.

Comment: Is your visa single-entry or multiple-entry?

Comment: @ZachLipton In all likelihood multiple, as she's a VWP national. That said it's irrelevant, as she won't be using it for her transit in December

Comment: You seem to be very confused about the terms of your visa. Please look at the visa and note the number of entries and expiration date.

Comment: @Crazydre the only way a holder of a B-2 visa can use the VWP and therefore ESTA is to be a dual national and travel on the passport that doesn't have the visa in it.

Comment: @phoog I see, didn't know that. However as a VWP national, in 99% likelihood she has a 10-year multi viSA

Answer (score 4):

Your question seems to be based on a misconception that your visa allows a single six-month period of admission to the United States.  If your visa is a multiple entry visa, then it is valid for multiple trips to the United States, and normally *each* of those trips will be limited to six months.

If an immigration officer decides that you may be using the visa improperly to spend more time in the US than outside it, subsequent trips may be limited to shorter periods.  However, if your second use of the visa occurs after a transit through the United States, this is very unlikely to happen.

It's likely that when you attempt to transit with your visa that the border officer will refuse entry under the VWP and admit you with the visa.  This would be a problem only if your visa is good for a single entry.  As Crazydre notes, this is very unlikely, since most citizens of VWP countries get 10-year multiple-entry B-2 visas.

If you don't already have ESTA authorization, and if your visa is a multiple-entry visa, then you should save yourself the $14 and refrain from applying for ESTA.

Comment: I second this answer

Answer (score 2):

US visas have an issue date, and an expiry date.  The only time-based criteria for the visa is that you can only use it to enter the US up until the expiry date.  There are no "valid for X months after first use" style conditions on a US visa.

Presuming your visa is a multi-entry visa (and almost all B2 visas are), then you can use it to enter the US as many times as you want, up to (and including) the day it expires.

Thus yes, you can (and should) use your B2 visa to enter the US for the trip in December.  Doing so will not affect the validity of your B2 visa in any way. Attempting to enter using an ESTA/VWP will likely cause confusion, and has an additional cost, so there is absolutely no reason to do it.

Comment: Doesn't have an additional cost since she states she's already paid for the ESTA. If she hadn't, then certainly she shouldn't either